# NOT EXISTS improves performance?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I ran into a case where I realized the NOT EXISTS clause was making to run a query faster.

If we have a table Test (with about 500k records)

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
 ID bigint
 , Code varchar(20)
 , AddedDate datetime
)
```

if I want to insert the resulting data into a temporary table A

```
 DECLARE @A TABLE
 (
  ID bigint
 )
```

then we have  3 scenarios as follows:

1). Inserting all data without any restriction

```
INSERT @A
SELECT dh.ID
FROM TEST dh
```

The query runs in 7 - 8 seconds.

2). Adding NOT EXISTS with a code that does not exist

```
INSERT @A
SELECT dh.ID
FROM TEST dh
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST d WHERE d.Code = 'bbbb')
```

The query runs in about 4 seconds

3). Adding NOT EXITS with a code that exits

```
INSERT @A
SELECT dh.ID
FROM TEST dh
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST d WHERE d.Code = 'AX8')
```

The query runs in 0 seconds.

The results for 3). makes sense, since the inner query has data, the NOT EXISTS will avoid to have result inserted into `@A` table so the time will be the lowest, 0 seconds in this case.

But why 2) run faster than 1).

Comment: Have you created an index on Test?

Comment: Not really, just those fields on the description.